# JavaFX How to put FXML Controller Instance to HashMap?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have many FXML with different Controller and I want to access all Controller Instance in one class using static methods. The reason I am doing this because I want to change the UI of different FXML from different controller. I'm not sure if there is any better way to do it. My problem is in my SceenViews class because I don't know what datatype to use to hold FXML Controller Instance in my controllerMap variable.

Inside my Package: Main.java, ScreenViews.java, Frame.FXML, FrameController.java, Login.FXML, LoginController.java, Dashboard.FXML, DashboardController.java, Journal.FXML, and JournalController.java

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application { 
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception { 
    ScreenViews.loadFXML("Frame", "Frame.fxml");
    ScreenViews.loadFXML("Login", "Login.fxml");
    ScreenViews.loadFXML("Dashboard", "Dashboard.fxml"); 
    ScreenViews.loadFXML("Journal", "Journal.fxml");        
    Scene scene = new Scene((Parent) ScreenViews.getView("Frame"));
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}    

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}     
}
```

In my ScreenViews.java what datatype can I use to hold different controller instance in my controllerMap variable?

```
public class ScreenViews {
private static HashMap<String, Node> viewMap = new HashMap<>();
//HASHMAP FOR CONTROLLER INSTANCE
private static HashMap<String, datatype? > controllerMap = new HashMap<>();

public static void addView(String name, Node screen) {
    viewMap.put(name, screen);
}

public static Node getView(String name) {
    return viewMap.get(name);
}   

public static void addController(String name,  datatype? controller) {
    controllerMap.put(name, controller);
}

public static datatype? getController(String name) {
    return controllerMap.get(name);
}

public static boolean loadFXML(String name, String resource) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader fxLoader = new 
        FXMLLoader(ScreenViews.class.getResource(resource));
        Parent loadedFXML = (Parent) fxLoader.load();
        addView(name, loadedFXML);
        addController(name, fxLoader.getController());
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Sample LoginController.java code

```
public class LoginController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    } 

    @FXML
    public void frameSetUI(ActionEvent event) {
        ScreenViews.getController("Frame").getFramePane().getChildren().add(ScreenViews.get("Dashboard"));
    }
}
```

Sample FrameController.java code

```
public class FrameController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private StackPane rootPane;
    @FXML private AnchorPane titleBar;
    @FXML private AnchorPane framePane;
    @FXML private Button toDashboard;
    @FXML private AnchorPane mainPane;

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 
    }

    public AnchorPane getFramePane(){
        return framePane;  
    }

}
```

Comment: Show a couple of examples of controllers...

Comment: I believe what Jim meant was to show the controller class code in the post , so that it can be better understood and help you with appropriate response

Comment: I've added sample Controller code.

Comment: *"I don't know what datatype to use to hold FXML Controller Instance in my controllerMap"* `java.lang.Object` or perhaps even `Initializable`, but the latter one would require you to use the interface for every controller, so better use `Object`...

Comment: @fabian I've try using object and it works but I still need to Cast it to the Controller if I'm going to use it. Like this one for FrameController Instance ((FrameController) ScreenViews .getController("Frame")). Is getting a controller instance really need casting?

Comment: Let `V` denote the value type of your `Map`. To assing a object `x` as value to the map, the type of `x` needs to be `V` or a type that extends `V`. For the controllers you've shown the common supertype is `java.lang.Object` (concerning classes) and also both implement `Initializable`. Therefore `V` can either be `Object` or `Initializable`. If both controllers contain common functionality you want to access, you could create a interfact or superclass for it which would allow  you to access more funtionality via `V` but to get to the exact type, a cast is inevitable.